# Is there a way to receive telegram messages in node.js without bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram

I would like to have a very simple client in nodejs (an example) that can receive messages from specific channels and groups in telegram. I just searched in internet but I only get bot samples. I want to receive group messages in what I don't have access to give privileges to my bot so I would like to know if I can receive my own messages with no bot as intermediary.

Comment: Take a look at [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/)

Comment: thanks, i just looked at it but i don't understand how to use it or what is the library to install. I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [Getting Started](https://core.telegram.org/#getting-started) section to learn more about your first steps.
In short:

1. Create your client application
2. Get your `app_id`
3. Establish user authorization
4. Learn more about [channels](https://core.telegram.org/api/channel)
5. Use [channel methods](https://core.telegram.org/methods#working-with-channelssupergroupsgeogroups) to work with channel messages

Comment: I can't find out how to use telegram API on js or nodejs in telegram doc!

Comment: @Behzad Why are you expecting this information to be in the Telegram docs?
Node.js is just a client env to work with Telegram API. Consider reading [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/) to learn how to invoke API methods or using the existing modules, like [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) or [telegraf.js](https://telegraf.js.org)